# How do I enable spark-sql on DataStax Version 5.1.7?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I want to use spark-sql in DataStax but it did not start  with dse by default.
So How do I configure spark-sql in dse 5.1.7?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about SparkSQL Thrift server? Yes, it doesn't start by default - you can fix it by adding script that will execute

```
dse spark-sql-thriftserver start
```

after DSE starts.

See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSqlThriftServer.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks ..will try

Comment: I tried but getting following error 
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.datastax.bdp.fs.model.NoSuchFileException: File not found: /tmp/hive/

Comment: commented in your question